Can't iterate over dataset (AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'complex'.)
I'm using:
windows
python version 3.10.0
datasets==2.21.0
numpy==1.24.4

I tried to iterate over dataset I just downloaded:
from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset("jacktol/atc-dataset", download_mode='force_redownload')


dataset['train'][0]

and got error:
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'complex'.
`np.complex` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `complex`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `complex` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.complex128` here.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations

which numpy and datasets do I need iterate over the datasets ?

The error is due to the deprecation (in NumPy version 1.20) and removal (in NumPy version 1.24 NumPy Doc 1.24) of the np.complex alias in NumPy.
To resolve you can try updating the datasets library:
pip install --upgrade datasets

and/ or downgrading NumPy to before the removal:
E.g.
pip install numpy==1.23.5

